# logical right shift in python - meaning of the expression (num % 0x100000000) >> 1

Tags: python, bit-manipulation, logical-operators

In java, as we have '>>>' for logical right shift operation which is missing in Python.
I have come across this expression:

```
(num % 0x100000000) >> 1
```

I'm trying to understand how this works and make sense of it so that I don't have to memorize.

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, Python does have `>>` but doesn't have a triple operator like `>>>`.  `>>` does a bitwise right shift:

https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators

The `>>>` operator in Java shifts bits to the right "unsigned", which means that the newest leftmost bit is always a `0` bit.  (A "signed" shift would copy the sign bit, so would have a `0` bit for a positive integer value and a `1` bit for a negative integer value.)

Java has a concept of a variable of a particular size: you can have a 32-bit integer, or a 64-bit integer, etc.  In Python we just have objects of type `int` which are arbitrary precision (they have as many bits of storage as needed so very large values can be stored).  So in your code snippet our first step is to make sure that our integer value is maximum 32 bits.

I don't know where you found this example, but it's mixing a modulus operation with bit-shifting.  The constant `0x100000000` is `2**32`.  Modulus finds the remainder left over after a division.  So this modulus operation will keep just the lowest 32 bits of an integer value.

Personally I would do that operation with a logical AND:

`x & 0xff_ff_ff_ff`  (note that the underscores are legal "sugar" in Python 3.x; they don't do anything but we can use them to separate groups of digits.  In this case I used them to separate bytes, to make it clear that this is four `0xff` bytes strung together to make `2**32 - 1`

This assert will not fire on my computer because the two values are equal:
`assert x & 0xff_ff_ff_ff == x % 0x100000000`

But the modulus operator has one advantage: it should provide the lower bits of the number no matter whether you run that code on a "big-endian" computer or a "little-endian" computer.  I'm using an AMD 64-bit processor, which is x86, which means it's little-endian.  (I'm not actually sure how the bitwise AND would work in Python on a big-endian system; I have some experience with C on big-endian systems but not Python.  It might actually work!  But the modulus is certain to work.)

So, having isolated the lower 32 bits of the value, we then want to right-shift by 1 bit.  We always need to be careful of operator precedence to make sure things happen in the correct order; in this case, explicit parentheses guarantee that the shift happens after we take just the lowest 32 bits.

When the modulus grabs the lower 32 bits, the result is never negative: it will be an integer in the range from `0` to `0xff_ff_ff_ff` inclusive.  So when right-shifting the high bit will for sure be a `0` bit.  Therefore this code snippet is guaranteed to produce the same thing as putting an integer value into a Java 32-bit integer variable and then right-shifting using `>>>`.

Comment: Endianness of the computer or the Python implementation is irrelevant here. That's internal, doesn't make any difference when you're just working with the numbers as numbers. I'd btw write `% 2**32` , easier to write and read.

Comment: @superbrain I try to be careful with endian issues.  Since I'm not set up to test the behavior on a big-endian system right now, I just said I wasn't sure.  I think you could be right that it doesn't actually matter.

Comment: The way you talk about bytes when talking about `0xff_ff_ff_ff` sounds like you might be thinking about that on a lower level than it is. That's not four bytes, it's just an integer literal written in hexadecimal. Won't even result in four 0xff bytes *internally*, as Python uses 30-bit digits. You'd only deal with bytes if you used for example `int.to_bytes` or `int.from_bytes`, but then you're specifying the endianness, for example `(1234).to_bytes(2, 'big')`. And the `&` operation operates on two ints. Doesn't matter whether they're internally big or little endian, they'll both use the same.

Answer (score 3):

That expression has little to do with the difference between logical and arithmetic shifts, the latter which preserves sign (the leftmost bit when you're talking about two's complement number).

In the expression in your question, `num % 0x100000000` simply strips off anything to the left of the rightmost 32 bits, to ensure the value you're shifting is coerced into the 32-bit range `0 - 0xffffffff`. Then the `>> 1` shifts that right. Because you've coerced the range, you will be guaranteed to get a `0` shifting into the leftmost bit, even if your input value is something weird like `0xffffffff12345678`.